# SQL Server 2008: Delete database while Rollback is in progress

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

I am trying to remove a test database in which a database modification failed. The resources being consumed by the rollback action in SQL are affecting production databases (users reporting slow queries etc)

This is not an ideal situation, unfortunately seperate production and test servers are a rarity amongst my customer base.

Drop existing connections also fails when trying to delete the database.

I cannot set the database into Single_user mode as it is being locked by the rollback.

I do not care about the data integrity of this database - it just needs to be deleted, though other databases on the instance must not be affected.

**Is there a method to cancel any existing roll back transactions and permanently delete a database?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do this by enabling activity monitor by right clicking the server name on the Left Pane of the SQL MGMT studio.

[image]

Then you can filter all the processes associated with your test db and end process

then you can delete your test db

Note:This method may not be suitable for databases in use and databases without backup!

You can also do this by starting/stopping sql services and again only suitable for test databases that you don't need any data from.

Comment: The question was specifically related to a database in use - it was rolling back transactions.  End process did not stop the roll back and did nothing to speed it up.

We could not stop services as the instance had production databases on it.

Comment: In that case, you can may try digging deeper into sql process with proc mon[Systernals] to see if you can find any other process associate with that test db and terminate that or wait for it finish. Or restart services or server if a planned maintenance on the server is due soon.